# express 4 + angularjs route and refresh

Tags: angularjs, express

I have planned to  run Multiple SPA(angularjs) under single domain, I have 2 route and both routes are served under different index page as follows.

```
 var appRouter = express.Router();
 var webRouter = express.Router();


 webRouter.use(function(req,res){
 res.sendFile('Index1.html', { root: __dirname });  ;       
 });

 appRouter .use(function(req,res){
 res.sendFile('Index2.html', { root: __dirname });  ;       
 });
```

My problem is while refreshing a page, express sends **Cannot GET /url**. How to resolve this common issue with multiple routes, though single route just need

```
 app.use(function(req,res){
 res.sendFile('Index.html', { root: __dirname });   ;       
 });
```

I have tried mouthpath

```
 app.use(webRouter); 
 app.use(appRouter );
```

but it doesn't helped me because Top one is considered and requested urls path is in **appRouter**.Is this possible, if so  I'm glad, I found setting dynamic  app.use(something) is the only way. Do someone knew the way to do it.

Comment: you should analyse the request prior to directing it somewhere (this will require some custom code). Otherwise you should namespace your applications with some url part. And lastly this can be better done with 2 separate applications in normal settings and with web server set up to direct requests to one of them based e.g. on host name.

Comment: What you are doing here is: hey, capture all requests and user webRouter. and then after web router use appRouter. This implies that webRouter will send data down the middleware stack, but it won't as I understand as it's returning respose up. this is the nature of middleware and how Express works AFAIK.

Comment: Your first comment gives more meaning to this question. Thanks a lot..cheers